Springboot web project is not showing in local host : 8080 of Tomcat Server
When I host a local host 8080 of tomcat server with Intelij (for Springboot project), it shows the login page of localhost:8080/login(with. Username and password) instead of my project's interface.If I change the /login into my page (/users) it again load the /login page.If I give the username and password it shows an Error of "No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken".
How to fix this issue.?

I think that you have defined spring-boot-starter-security as a dependency. This behaviour is then the default configuration. So you have to configure Spring Security the way you want it or you have to disable Spring Security.

Problem is quite simple, your pom had  spring-boot-stater-security. This will force you to login first before any other work.

Thank you bro... I found solution for it...

@Dinesh_DK no problem, I am willing to answer

I added these lines to the file application.properties & then in that page (login page show below) i give the respective user-name and password. Then my page is showing..
spring.security.user.name=<your_username>
spring.security.user.password=<your_password>
spring.security.user.roles=USER,ADMIN

The Login Page is :
https://i.sstatic.net/xFlFlvOi.png
